# Android Google Firebase Database Object Value

Tags: android, firebase, casting, firebase-realtime-database, type-conversion

I have seen many quirky things with Firebase; here is one, and not sure if I am missing something in documentation or someone else has run into this issue.

I am trying to save a number as a Double and depending on whether the value has only a value other than zero after decimal point will it store as a Double; otherwise, Firebase seems to convert type to Long. Notice this behavior when attempting to type in the web interface similar values.

Is there some trick to keeping it this way, or a work around to my use case?

I am reading the value into a string format which has something to the effect of `String.format('%1$f', <Value>)`.

When coming to this statement, depending on whether Firebase has saved as a Double or Long determines whether I receive the exception.

Any simple fixes to this? I hate having to come up with a complex solution to something Google should not be assuming when saving the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the model class' setter to check if the object returned from firebase is a `Double` or a `Long` then convert the object to Double if it is a `Long`.

```
public class CustomClass {
    private Double value;

    public CustomClass() {}

    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Double) {
            this.value = (Double) value;
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            this.value = Double.valueOf((Long)value);
        }
    }
}
```